# What is the exact name of post-hoc test?

Tags: bootstrap, multiple-comparisons, post-hoc

I ran a bootstrapping post-hoc test in R software, but it gives no information about the name of the post-hoc test (like Tukey, Bonferroni, etc.)?
Here is the documentation for the function:
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/WRS2/versions/1.1-3/topics/t1waybt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a test created by the book's author, Rand Wilcox.  It's probably best to describe it by the description of the function: "Test of equal trimmed means using a percentile *t* bootstrap method", or "heteroscedastic one-way ANOVA for trimmed means by bootstrap". And simply cite the package and function.